# How can I turn a string into its literal representation?

Tags: elisp, string

```
(mystery-function "a neat\nstring\"")
=> "\"a neat \\nstring\\\""
```

This question was asked on `freenode#emacs` by user `dropdrive`.  How could I write (or use) a function that takes a string literal and returns the string literal that, when `read`, would return the original string?  That is,

```
(let ((s (any-string)))
  (should (equal s (read (mystery-function s)))))
```

Note that this `let`-form is a bit misleading – the session at the very top of this question should be used for testing. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: I don't understand your purpose: in particular, `"\"a neat \\nstring\\\""` cannot be `read`, while the output of `(prin1-to-string "a neat\nstring\"")` can (even with "expanded" newline characters)...

Comment: @T.Verron The purpose, I would believe, would be to use the function to insert literal strings for other languages that use escape sequences.  I am not the original asker though so I don't know the original intent, but this is how I would use it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're looking for `prin1-to-string`. Also, set `print-escape-newlines` to a true value to get the `"\n"` behavior you specified.

I.e.:

```
(let ((print-escape-newlines t))
  (prin1-to-string "foo\nbar"))
=> "\"foo\\nbar\""
```

Comment: +1, but what about `\r`, `\t`, etc.?  Sorry that I didn't formulate the question completely – I didn't think there'd be a ready-made solution for `\n` that didn't account for the other sequences :(

Comment: Only `\n` and `\f` are affected by `print-escape-newlines` (now I have no idea why `\f` is a newline, but here we are). I'm afraid you are out of luck for the others, as the other `print-escape-*` variables do not affect them.

Comment: Also note, you can use the %S in `format` or `message` and it will print like `prin1`

Answer (score 8):

This is not exactly the purpose it was invented for, but seems to be useful:

```
(require 'json)
(json-encode-string "a neat\nstring\" with tab\t and feed \f, also vertical tab \v")
"\"a neat\\nstring\\\" with tab\\t and feed \\f, also vertical tab \\u000b\""
```

Comment: Well, I'll be. +1